# How to get all pixel color of desktop and invert (negative) them

Tags: c#, colors, desktop

My client asked me to make a button in his user form and, when clicked, invert color of all desktop (Like accessibility setting).
I tried to see if there was a specific method to do so but unfortunately i didn't find anything native .

So i'm trying to invert color of all Desktop pixel with a button into a user form.
I do not search to invert the color of a bitmap image, but All screen color
i don't know how am i supposed to do since this is the first time someone ask me for this kind of function

i manage to get all pixel of the screen using this snippet :

```
        int height = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height
        int width = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width

        for(int y = 0; y<height; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x<width; x++)
            {

               //What am i supposed to code here to get all pixel color and invert them? 
            }

        }
```

But here i don't know what can i do to get the color and change them to negatives ones?
I saw around some tutorial explaining how to do with a bitmap image but here it's all the screen/desktop that needs to swith to negative colors.

Any idea how can i do it? Is there a function i can overide or something ? As i said, this is the first time someone ask me for something like this and i have absolutly no idea on how can i do this.

Comment: Wait, are you talking about inverting them in a screenshot, or switching the system into an inverted colour mode. They are two very different questions. Your current code looks like the former, but your question sounds like the latter. I think perhaps [this application](https://github.com/mlaily/NegativeScreen) might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Acctually I'm more talking about switching system into inverted color, i did not find any specific native function to do so, i don't want a screeshot to be changed i want the actual system screen color to be inverted

Comment: Do you mean `High Contrast` http://usability.com.au/windows-7-change-colour-contrast/ ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm searching to do, but programmatically with C#

Comment: Please make that clearer in your question.

Comment: Inverting doesn't create high contrast. To change it (transparently) you may want to install a new icc profile to video driver. (either transforming a standard sRGB file or by reading the original one and inverting [some screen install a better icc profile). So transformation is done by video card. [There are already few inverted icc, just to test that programs understand icc [the other use of icc: characterising the input, so the image)